# Is there any way to remove a playing video with css?

Tags: css, video

After reading [this](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko%3aMoving_Plugins_To_Content), I know that Firefox won't stop a playing video even if I change it to `display:none` (unlike Chrome). I wonder if there's any workaround to do so with css only (not javascript)?

Comment: What about the using 'visibility' property in Firefox? Or perhaps setting 'Content' to none?

Comment: @Art 'visibility' won't work, and I dont know how to use 'Content' here.